# How to iterate in query result set returned by findBy method of Doctrine in Smfony 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to replace some chars of a column of result set. I'm calling following to make the DB query and get the results:

```
   $applicant = $em2->getRepository('TestBundle:Person')->findByApplicantName($searchText);
```

This return the result set from repository class, and I'm able to send the variable into Twig template to show the result via paginator in this way:

```
    {% for applicant in pagination %}
    <tr>
    <td>
    {{ applicant.person_address }}
    </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

How can I iterate in the returned query result in the controller before handing it to Twig template? I created following function, but I don't know how to reach individual column of the returned result set and replace it with itself again:

```
foreach ($applicant as $a) {
// $a->person_address ?? it is also ok to replace chars in all columns
$a = str_replace("Ã¼", "ü", $a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a->getPerson_address(); // Retrieves the address, might want to rethink some of your names
```